# How to match 0 and an empty string, but not 0 and undefined, and not 0 and null, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, equality

So basically, I want to have the program return `true` when an equality test is put with `0` and an empty string (""). Then, I could use the following without any error:

```
0 == ""; // true
```

But I don't want to match:

```
0 == null
0 == undefined
"" == null
"" == undefined
```

I want them all to return `false`. How is this possible? I don't think there's an operator for this, so is there a way I can change their values to make this work somehow?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it okay to have a function that returns what you want, or do you need to make existing code (that uses `==`) behave differently?

Comment: Just tested on Chrome dev-tools and your last 4 statement do return false, and your first statement do return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Equals(a,b) {

   if(a===b || (a===0 && b === "") || (a==="" && b === 0)) return true;
    return false;

}
```

You can look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p5Ek/) example.

Comment: Compared to Chuck Norris, everyone equals zero.

Comment: @Thilo Check that, every one and every type.

Answer (score 1):

```
function eq(value) {
    return (value === 0 || value === "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "not really".

You can't put them up against each other like that, and expect it to work.
Use `||` and use two statements, but use `===`, instead of `==`.

The double-operator will try to cast to different types.
The triple-operator requires them to be the same type.

```
0 == "" // true
0 === "" // false


(testValue === 0 || testValue === "") // will return false for undefined/null/NaN/false
```